# How to use Ehcache to cache the jsp pages?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, jsp, gwt, ehcache

We are on the development of gwt-web application with Google App Engine. Now our application became slow due to lot of jstl logic in jsp pages.Earlier i wanted to use memcache service of appengine but after reading some documents, came to know that 'Ehcache' is better than memcache with gae support.

Correct me if I am wrong and please respond me with appropriate solution if anybody have idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Echache's manual on web caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/modules/web-caching)?

Alternatively, you can have a look at [OSCache tag library](http://svn.opensymphony.com/svn/oscache/tags/v2_2-rc/src/etc/oscache.tld). It should be fairly trivial to rewrite the `CacheTag` class to use Ehcache instead of OSCache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mindas                                            Will that  Echache's web caching support gwt-web application?

Comment: What I have suggested applies to JSPs in general, however I have no experience with gwt-web so can't really give any assurance, sorry.